# Assign outlet IP for a libvirt VM using routed network

Tags: libvirt, firewalld, nftables

My host network interface has got two IPs. Currently, I'm running my VMs in a **routed** network.

Host's network interface is a member of `public` zone in `firewalld`, with both **forward** and **masquerade** enabled.

With the setup described before, the VM is able to connect to the Internet and I can add port forwardings to VM with `firewalld`'s `--add-forward-port`.

However, now I want to change one of my VMs' outlet IP (the IP that *masqueraded* to) to another IP that available in my host's network interface.
I've tried to add a `SNAT` rule to my `nftables` since `firewalld` doesn't support it. The command I used was `nft add rule nat POSTROUTING snat to ip saddr map { <VM's IP> : <public ip> }`, this causes the VM disconnected from the Internet but still be able to connect with port forwarding set in `firewalld`.

I searched Google about this and didn't find much information about this.

Here are some configurations.

The default public IP is redacted to `10.0.0.1`, and the secondary public IP is redacted to `10.0.0.2`.

The VM 1's NAT IP is redacted to `192.168.122.1`, and the VM 2's NAT IP is redacted to `192.168.122.2`.

FirewallD

```
libvirt (active)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  target: ACCEPT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0
  sources: 
  services: custom--ms-wbt-server-ms-wbt-server dhcp dhcpv6 dns ssh tftp
  ports: 
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule priority="32767" reject

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp1s0f0
  sources: 
  services: cockpit dhcpv6-client libvirt libvirt-tls mdns ssh steam-streaming vnc-server
  ports: 
  protocols: 
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.2" forward-port port="33412" protocol="tcp" to-port="3389" to-addr="192.168.122.2" # another public ip is the ip that i want to change to
        rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.1" forward-port port="33411" protocol="udp" to-port="3389" to-addr="192.168.122.1" # default public ip is the default outlet ip
        rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.1" forward-port port="33411" protocol="tcp" to-port="3389" to-addr="192.168.122.1"
        rule family="ipv4" destination address="10.0.0.2" forward-port port="33412" protocol="udp" to-port="3389" to-addr="192.168.122.2"
```

virsh

```
<network connections='2'>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>(network uuid)</uuid>
  <forward mode='route'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='<mac address>'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

`ip addr`

```
enp1s0f0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <mac address> brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd <broadcast addr> scope global noprefixroute enp1s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.2/25 brd <broadcast addr> scope global noprefixroute enp1s0f0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route`

```
default via <default public ip gateway> dev enp1s0f0 proto static metric 100 
<default public ip subnet> dev enp1s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.1 metric 100 
<secondary public ip subnet> dev enp1s0f0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2 metric 100 
<virsh network subnet> dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

My server is running `Fedora 37` with `firewalld 1.2.2` and `nftables 1.0.4`.